# Get Gradle classpath from command line

Tags: maven, gradle

With Maven, I can print the build classpath with this command:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

Is there a similar command I can use with Gradle from the command line, preferably without having to modify any of the build scripts?

Answer (score 2):

You can list all the dependencies in a configuration from CLI:

```sh
gradle dependencies --configuration=runtimeOnly
```

Or you can do that via a task:

```
task classPath {
    doFirst {
        configurations.runtimeOnly.each { println it }
        
        // This should probably work as well:
        // sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.each { println it}
    }
}
```

Comment: `gradle dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath` is what worked for me.